# Newbie async.waterfall

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I tried use async.
I have a rout function with a async.waterfall.
The 1st function call an external function and fetch all users in usersData
The 2nd function, via async.each, it call an external function to search infos for each user.
I want pass again usersData with the news values to the 3th function.
In the 3th function, for the moment, I have a async.each and I watch the datas for each user. 
My issues

1) In the second function, I don't fetch the information for each user.
2) The 3th function is called before the 2nd and I don't fetch the new data
Thanks

```
router.post('/launch',function(req,res,next){
    async.waterfall([
        function(cb){
          // fetch the global users  
          fetchUsers(usersData,cb);
        },
        function(usersData,cb){
            async.each(usersData,
                function(userdata,cb){
                    // fetch other data for each user
                    calcBalance(userdata, cb);
                },function(err){
                    cb(err,usersData);
                });
        },
        function(usersData,cb){
            async.each(usersData,
                function(userdata,cb) {
                    //watch the info with the news data
                    console.log(' 2 '+ JSON.stringify(userdata));
                    //console.log(3);
                }
            );
        },
        ],
        function(err,results){
            console.log('Fin' + JSON.stringify(results));
            res.render('synchros',{launch:'end'},results);
        });
    res.render('synchros',{launch:'end'});
});

function calcBalance(userData,cb){
    var user_id=userData.id,
        resultCalcBalance=0,
        cats_id=[3,4,6],
        tabData={};
    async.each(cats_id,function(cat_id,cb){
    switch (cat_id) {
        case 3:
            var comp = "<=";
            break;
        case 4:
            var comp = "<=";
            break;

        case 6:
            var comp = "<";
            break;
    }// fin du switch

        var myquery = "select blabla+
        //console.log(calcul_balance);
        connectionMysql.query(myquery, function (err, rows, fields,cb) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error ' + err);
                cb(err);
            }
            else if (rows.length != 0) {
                if (rows != 0) {
                }// end if
                else {

                }// end else
        }); // end connectionMysql
    },function(err){
        cb(err,userData); // ?? I send the data here
    });
    cb(null, userData); // ?? I send the data here ??
}
```

Comment: what's happening with the data coming back from the db? also, make sure `cb` gets called inside of the callback function that gets passed to `.query` (right now it only gets called if there's an error, it seems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reindented, fixed some typos, and changed the names of the callbacks. I changed the second async.each to async.map because you're processing an array to get a set of one result per item.

The first problem was in the second to last line. You were calling back too early from calcBalance.
Another potential problem was an ambiguous callback name `cb` in the second waterfall function (as well as in calcBalance.)

Finally, you never ran the async.each callback in the third waterfall function, and if you calledback out of it, it was accidental.

You still aren't ever reporting success from one database query, so you will need to call `done()` if it worked. You might also want to use `async.map` for the database calls, this would let you assemble the results, like `done(null, balanceForCategory)`

```
router.post('/launch', function(req, res, next){
  async.waterfall([
    function(done){
      // fetch the global users
      fetchUsers(usersData,done);
    },
    function(usersData,done){
      async.map(usersData, function(userdata, done2){
        // fetch other data for each user
        calcBalance(userdata, done2);
      },function(err, results){
        done(err,usersData);
      });
    },
    function(usersData, done){
      async.each(usersData, function(userdata, done2) {
        //watch the info with the news data
        console.log(' 2 '+ JSON.stringify(userdata));
        //console.log(3);
      }, done)
    },
  ],
  function(err, results){
    // results will be undefined because we called done() from the above async.each
    console.log('Fin' + JSON.stringify(results));
    res.render('synchros', {launch:'end'}, results);
  }); // end of async.each
}); // end of router.post()

function calcBalance(userData, callback){
  var user_id=userData.id,
  resultCalcBalance=0,
  cats_id=[3,4,6],
  tabData={};
  async.each(cats_id, function(cat_id, done){
    switch (cat_id) {
    case 3:
        var comp = "<=";
        break;
    case 4:
        var comp = "<=";
        break;

    case 6:
        var comp = "<";
        break;
    }// fin du switch

    var myquery = "select blabla";
    //console.log(calcul_balance);
    connectionMysql.query(myquery, function (err, rows, fields, queryCb) { // what is this queryCb param?
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error ' + err);
        queryCb(err); // This will callback whatever mySql passed in as queryCb
        // done(err)  // This will callback out of the async.each iterator and immediately the async.each callback
        // callback(err)  // This will callback out of calcBalance and continue executing
        // return callback(err); // This will callback out of calcBalance and stop executing
      } else if (rows.length != 0) {
        if (rows != 0) {
        // Your code might hang here without calling a callback
      } else {
        // Your code might hang here without calling a callback
      }
    }); // end connectionMysql
  },function(err){
    // Inside async.each callback. Either everything worked or something broke
    callback(err,userData); // Send the data back out of calcBalance
  });

  //callback(null, userData); // Running this here will IMMEDIATELY call back before async.each runs
}
```

Comment: Hi Plato, Thanks for your response and for the corrections. Effectually it's more simple and comprehensible for my mind. The problem, the 3th function is not called. I correct and after I copy your code and the issue is the same.

Comment: Start inserting console.log statements to see which callbacks are run. Did you fix the `async.each` inside `calcBalance` to make sure you always call `done()` in all situations?

Comment: Sorry for my novice questions. I can watch function1 and function2 run :. But how can I know if callbacks run ? I post my calcBalance function. Thanks very much for your patience. mdouke

Comment: Output something as the first line of the callback, for example: `console.log('Inside the database callback')`. I suggest placing them: as the first line of calcBalance, as the first line of the `async.each` iterator function inside calcBalance, and as the first line of the `connection.query` callback function

Comment: Ok,In calcBalance, all it's correct. at the end, I have :

Comment: Ok,In calcBalance, all it's correct. at the end, I have :  console.log('1 '+JSON.stringify(userData));
And in the console.log, I can watch each record  of async.each iterator. I don't understand why it stop at the end of 2nd and it don't start the third.  If I cut the 2nd function, it works. Why a function can stop the program ? It'a a mismatch for me and I don't know the direction of the solution. Tks

Comment: Whatever that `queryCb` is its probably wrong. Look at my comments, you need to tell the `async.each` in the `calcBalance` function that you have got the balances for a category. Do that with `done('problem')` or `done(null, balance)`. If you don't call `done()` the `async.each()` call will hang and never get to its own callback (and thus it will never trigger the calcBalance callback, and thus you never get to the third waterfall function.)

Comment: I follow your comments. I replace the querycb by done in the if(err). I add done(null,userData) async.each(cats_id,
        function(cat_id,done){

Comment: Tks for your help but I dont see where add done(null,userData) in the calcBalance. At the end of the  function(cat_id,done){the code },done(null,userData). The problem is the same at the end of     async.each(cats_id,
        function(cat_id,done){
},done(null,userdata)). It say done is not defined.

Comment: `done(null, userData)` would be called somewhere inside the database query. Probably near `console.log('1 '+JSON.stringify(userData));`. Unless you had a problem, when you correctly call `done(err)`. can you update your calcBalance function with your current attempt?

Comment: Yes, I saw your comments and I add just n ow. Ant it works. Thank you very very much. ;-)

Comment: congrats! please upvote or accept my answer if you have enough reputation to do so :)

Answer (score 1):

The calcBalance function

```
function calcBalance(userData,callback){
    // Ensuite on va calculer les rtt_balances et holiday_balances et yesterday_extra_hours_month
    var user_id=userData.id,
        resultCalcBalance=0,
        cats_id=[3,4,6],
        tabData={},
        dateJour=moment().format('YYYY-M-D');;

    async.each(cats_id,function(cat_id,done){
    switch (cat_id) {
        case 3:
            var comp = "<=";
            break;
        case 4:
            var comp = "<=";
            break;

        case 6:
            var comp = "<";
            break;
    }// fin du switch

        var calcul_balance = "select * from table1"            
        connectionMysql.query(calcul_balance, function (err, rows, fields,queryCb) {
            if (err) {
                queryCb(err); // This will callback whatever mySql passed in as queryCb
                // done(err)  // This will callback out of the async.each iterator and immediately the async.each callback
                // callback(err)  // This will callback out of calcBalance and continue executing
                // return callback(err); // This will callback out of calcBalance and stop executing
                console.log('Error ' + err);
                queryCb(err);
            }
            else if (rows.length != 0) {
                if (rows != 0) {
                    // On va chercher les valuers sinon on les laisse à zéro par défaut.
                    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                        if (!isNaN(rows[j].amount) && rows[j].amount != null) {
                            resultCalcBalance += parseInt(Math.round(rows[j].amount * 100) / 100);
                            //console.log('ResultCalculBalance 1chiffre ' + parseInt(Math.round(rows[j].amount*100)/100) + ' 2chiffre' + resultCalcBalance);
                        } else {
                            resultCalcBalance += 0;
                            //console.log('ResultCalculBalance 2' + JSON.stringify(rows[j].amount));
                        }
                    } // fin du for k
                    //console.log('Resultat : ' + userData.id + ' ' + cat_id + ' ' + resultCalcBalance);
                    if (cat_id == 3) userData.holiday_balance = resultCalcBalance;
                    if (cat_id == 4) userData.rtt_balance = resultCalcBalance;
                    if (cat_id == 6) userData.yesterday_extra_hours_month = resultCalcBalance;
                }// fin du if
                else {
                    if (cat_id == 3) userData.holiday_balance = 0;
                    if (cat_id == 4) userData.rtt_balance = 0;
                    if (cat_id == 6) userData.yesterday_extra_hours_month = 0;
                }// fin du else
            }// de la condition err ou pas
            console.log('1 '+JSON.stringify(userData));
        });
    },function(err){
        callback(err,userData);
    });
    //callback(null, userData); // Running this here will IMMEDIATELY call back before async.each runs
```